# Tag merge: [http-etag] and [etag]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

The tags [http-etag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http-etag) and [etag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/etag) look the same to me. Should they be merged?

Comment: Best would be a synonym from etag to http-etag. Even though the latter is less used.

Comment: I was just about to submit the same request.